# Python PyQt6 deleteLater() and child widgets

Tags: python, pyqt6

I have a question of functionality that I am uncertain about.  I'm *not* stuck on code implementation, so there is no need to share code for this question.  I use

```
layout.removeWidget
widget.deleteLater()
```

a couple/few times in a project I'm building.  I once read here on SO that `deleteLater()` does not function as described when deleting a widget with child widgets.  The comment said that child widgets do not get deleted correctly, and will stay in memory, which could lead to memory bloat/leaks.  Simply put (my question), is this true?

The docs mention nothing of this that I could find.  And it was just one comment from years back, that was actually written for PyQt5 (or 4), I believe.  So, have any of you guys done any tests on this?  Is this a bug in older versions of PyQt that has been fixed, or was the commentor outright wrong?

As you can see from my question, my issue isn't how to write something, it's about behind the scenes functionality of `deleteLater()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is important to remember that PyQt (as PySide) is a *binding* to Qt, which is written in C++.

All Qt objects and functions are accessed from python using *wrappers*.

When a Qt object is created from Python, there are actually *two* objects:

- the C++ object;
- the python object that allows us to use the above Qt object;

The lifespan of those two objects may not always coincide. In fact, the C++ object can be destroyed while the python reference remains, or the other way around.

### C++ object destruction

`deleteLater()` is guaranteed to destroy the C++ objects along with any object for which they have ownership (including indirect ownership for grand[grand, ...]children). Note that the object is not destroyed immediately, but only as soon as control returns to the event loop: then the object emits the [`destroyed()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#destroyed) signal and after that all its children are destroyed along with it, recursively.

This will *not* delete the python reference, if it existed. For instance:

```py
class MyLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, value, parent=None):
        super().__init__(value, parent)
        self.value = value
```

If you keep a python reference to an instance of the class above, you will still be able to access its `self.value` even after the object has been destroyed with `deleteLater()`. If you try to access any Qt functions or properties, instead, you'll get an exception:

```py
>>> print(mylabel.value)
'some value'
>>> print(mylabel.text())
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type MyLabel has been deleted
```

So, the python object will obviously keep using memory resources until it get garbage collected (its reference count becomes 0). This can be a problem if you keep references to objects that have large memory footprint on their python side (i.e., a large numpy array).

### Python object destruction

Deleting a python reference doesn't guarantee the destruction of the Qt object, as it only deletes the python object. For instance:

```py
>>> parent = QWidget()
>>> label = MyLabel('hello', parent)
>>> parent.show()
>>> del label
>>> print(parent.findChild(QLabel).text())
'hello'
```

This is because when an object is added to a parent, that parent *takes ownership* of the child.

Note that Qt objects that have no parent will also get destroyed *when* all python references are destroyed as well.

That is the reason of one of the most common questions here on SO, when somebody is trying to create another window using a local reference and without any parent object, but the window is not shown because it gets immediately garbage collected.

Note that this is valid for Qt6 as it is for Qt5 and as it was for Qt4, and it is also for their relative python bindings.

Considering what written in the first part:

```py
>>> parent = QWidget()
>>> label = MyLabel('hello', parent)
>>> parent.show()
>>> del parent
>>> print(label.value)
'hello'
>>> print(label.text())
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type MyLabel has been deleted
```

So, what must be always kept in mind is *where* objects live, including their C++ *and* python properties and attributes. If you're worried about memory usage for standard (not python-subclassed) widgets, `deleteLater()` is always guaranteed to release the memory resources of those widgets, and you only need to ensure that no remaining python reference still exists (but that would be true for *any* python program).

Finally, some considerations:

- in some very complex situations it's not always possible to keep track of all python references, so it's possible that even if you destroyed a parent, the references to some children objects still exist;
- not all Qt objects are QObjects, and their usage, behavior or memory management depends both on Qt and the C++ implementation; those object can be sometimes destroyed when their python references are, or when Qt "decides so";
- not all QObjects take ownership of other QObjects when they are "added" to them: one common case is QAction, which can be shared among many objects (QMenu, QMenuBar, QToolBar, and even standard QWidgets); always look for the "...takes ownership" phrase in the documentation whenever in doubt;

Comment: Enlightening, @musicamante.  I am sort of a newcomer to coding, so have not delved into the depths of object deleting/garbage management in Python.  I've just been letting Python handle that up to this point.  But, based on your response, Qt will indeed delete it's objects when using `deleteLater()`.  So, until the day I "git good", I'll continue as I have been.  Thanks for your help once again, brother.  P.S. you're my Qt man.  Prior, I had experience with tkinter, and Brian Oakley was my tkinter man.  But, tkinter is weak stuff compared to Qt.

Comment: @malonn You're welcome! Consider that tkinter is just a GUI toolkit. Comparing it to Qt is valid only to the length of the QtWidgets module, but it's in fact a complete *framework*. So, yes, tkinter might be somehow inferior to Qt on the "visual" aspects (its "clunkiness" and limited support for advanced widgets), but that's where a fair comparison should end: tkinter doesn't aim to provide anything more than UI elements.

Comment: Learned from you again.  I thought toolkits and frameworks were synonymous.  I see a difference now.  There's all kinds of stuff I haven't even discovered yet in Qt.  Good stuff.